# Normal font in IEEEtran section heading

Tags: fonts, sectioning, ieeetran

While using `IEEEtran`, I want to enforce the letter 'f' to be small in section headings.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document} 
\section{Real fMRI Data}
\end{document}
```

However, `IEEEtran` by default makes all letters capital, with the first letter of each word a little taller.

I tried this

```
\section{Real\normalfont{f}MRI Data}
```

But then all the letters after that becomes small, which I don't want.

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for your problems - "all letters [becoming] small" - is because `\normalfont` is a *declaration* that changes the font from that point onward. Typical usage would be `{\normalfont ...}` instead of `\normalfont{...}`. Either way, you're better of changing the *shape* manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Real {\upshape f}MRI Data}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just as matter of taste: as the "f" was not designed to precede uppercase characters, I would add some spacing in "fM", e.g.; `\section{Real \textup{f}\kern .05em MRI Data}`

Answer (score -1):

Issuing `\scshape` command from the point you desire normalcy works great. That is the command issued in the `IEEEtrans` class.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \section{Real \normalfont{f}\scshape MRI Data}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Depending on the current font, `\normalfont` changes more than the shape, also family and series can be changed. Therefore, it is better to put the font change for `f` inside a group.